# Android SQLite database remove duplicates from query

Tags: android, sqlite, filter

I'm new to SQLite. I'm using this query in order to extract all rows from a column for a specific user:

```
        Cursor c = db.query(true, TABLE, COLUMN, USER + "= '" + user + "'", null, null, null, null, null);
```

This is an example of table:

```
|group-----ID|
|------------|
|one-------me|
|one------you|
|two-------me|
|one-------me|
```

So the query for user "me" extracts "one, two, one". How can I filter the result in order to obtain a value just one time? Like "one, two"

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Group By parameter with the appropriate column name:

```
Cursor c = db.query(true, TABLE, COLUMN, USER + "= '" + user + "'", null,
            "group", null, null, null);
```

---

Since there are nine parameters in this method and three nearly identical methods...

```
public Cursor query(boolean distinct, 
                    String table, 
                    String[] columns, 
                    String selection, 
                    String[] selectionArgs, 
                    String groupBy,          /* this one */
                    String having, 
                    String orderBy, 
                    String limit)
```