# MySQL remove duplicate values

Tags: mysql

I have a table called Notes and column name as id and name

eg datas

Id   name

1     DEV

2     Prod

3     Prod

4     Prod

5     SQL

From this above table I need to retrive the value like this

Id    name

1      DEV

2      Prod

5      SQL

Comment: do you want to retrieve or change in the database ?

Comment: I want to retrive the values from the table

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810208/android-sqlite-database-remove-duplicates-from-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(id), Name
FROM Notes
GROUP BY Name
```